# passing arguments to implemented method java

Tags: java, implementation, argument-passing

I have a class that implements Printable. I'm trying to somehow get values from text fields into the print method but can't seem to work out how to do it.

```
public class TreePrint extends javax.swing.JFrame implements Printable{
```

Then this is the action for when user has selected the items to print:

```
private void btnPrintActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                         
{
    goPrint();  
}

public void goPrint() 
{
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    job.setPrintable(new TreePrint());
   // boolean doPrint = job.printDialog();
    job.print();
}

@Override  
public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page) throws PrinterException {  
    Koks koksSelected = (Koks) combobox_skirne.getSelectedItem();  
    System.out.println(combobox_skirne.getSelectedItem());  
    if (page > 0) {  
        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;  
    }  
    System.out.println(koksSelected.getSkirne());    
    return PAGE_EXISTS;  
}
```

The problem is that I can't get the selected item or text value in the print method. I can get them in the go print or btnPrintActionPerformed, but in the print() it always shows the selected value that was there when the program was first run.
I can post more code if needed, but it is quite long. Im sure this is a basic problem with implemented methods but I couldn't find an answer to it.

This is a similar (the same?) question:
[Passing Parameters to the print method (JAVA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8324388/passing-parameters-to-the-print-method-java)

Answer (score 3):

If the parameters a available when you create the `TreePrint` object, add a new constructor with this fields. If not, set the parameters before you print with a public method in `TreePrint`. Example:

```
private TreePrint tp;

public void goPrint() 
{
    ...
    this.tp = new TreePrint();
    job.setPrintable(this.tp);
    ...
}

@Override  
public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page) throws PrinterException {  
    ...
    this.tp.setXYZParameters(para1, para2, paraN);
    ...
}
```

`TreePrint` example:

```
private Integer para1;
private Integer para2;
private Integer paraN;

public void setXYZParameters(...) {...}
```

Comment: Didn't manage to get it to work that way, but made it work with global variables, so It is all good :)

Comment: [Avoid using global variables](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad). I don't think there is a need for global variables in that case. If you add your code I'll see if I can replace the global variables :) .

Comment: I posted the code here, thanks in advance: http://pastie.org/private/dtntiqs72tz5lrcnxtm8yw